# Banner and interstitial error (admob cocos2d)

Tags: ios

I just finished my first app and now I'm adding the admob ads, I followed this tutorial https://github.com/MrCapone/MyAdMobController-iOS2 to do it, but the problem is that when I run the app, the interstitial and the banner do not appear. In the console I get this message:

> Banner loading error: Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=0 "Request
>   Error: Invalid ad request parameter… NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request
>   Error: Invalid ad request parameter(s). Check the Xcode console for
>   details.

Does anyone know how I can do to solve this?

Comment: Did you look at the request parameters?  What were they? Did you check the console for details?  What did it say?

Comment: <Google> Invalid Request: {
    "base_uri" = "https:";
    "enable_auto_click_protection" = 1;
    errors = "Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?";
    "google.afma.Notify_dt" = 1433688002846;
    "request_id" = 1;
    "request_scenario" = "online_request";
    type = unknown;
    "use_webview_loadurl" = 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

I Integrate Banner and Interstitial Ads both Ads in one Project.

My project issues are `ApplicationID` and `adsUnitID` Different. [check](https://apps.admob.com/v2/apps)

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "Here Created Application ID")

GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "Above Created Application AdUnitID")
```

Check `ApplicationID` and `adsUnitID` On portoal